# Electron Build Issues with Node.js Server

Tags: node.js, electron

/server/app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const net = require("net");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

let clients = [];
// const dataArr = [];
const dataArr = Array.from({ length: 99 }, () => ({
  NAME: null,
  TEMPOUT: null,
  HUMOUT: null,
  HEATING: false,
  COOLING: false,
  AUTO: false,
  TLHVL: null,
  TLLVL: null,
  HUMOP: null,
}));
let sockets = [];

const addClient = (host, port, index) => {
  console.log(host, port, index);
  clients[index] = { host, port };
};

app.get("/client", (req, res) => {
  res.send(clients);
});

app.get("/fetch", (req, res) => {
  res.send(dataArr);
});

app.get("/connect/:ip/:port/:index", (req, res) => {
  const { ip, port, index } = req.params;
  addClient(ip, port, index);
  // res.send(`Client connected: ${ip}:${port}`);
});

app.get("/setting", (req, res) => {
  if (sockets.length <= 1) {
    sockets.forEach((socket, index) => {
      socket.end();
    });
  }

  sockets = clients.map((server, index) => {
    const socket = net.createConnection(server, () => {
      // console.log(`Connected to ${server.host}:${server.port}`);
      // console.log(index);
    });

    // 데이터 수신 이벤트 처리
    socket.on("data", (data) => {
      // console.log(`Received data from ${server.host}:${server.port}`);
      // console.log(data.toString());
      // dataArr[index] = JSON.parse(data.toString());

      try {
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        dataArr[index] = jsonData;
      } catch (err) {
        // console.error("Received invalid JSON data:", err);
      }
    });

    // 연결 종료 이벤트 처리
    socket.on("end", () => {
      // console.log(`Disconnected from ${server.host}:${server.port}`);
    });

    // 에러 발생 이벤트 처리
    socket.on("error", (err) => {
      // console.log(`Error occurred in ${server.host}:${server.port}: ${err}`);
    });

    return socket;
  });
  res.send("");
});

// HTTP 서버 연결
app.get("/message", (req, res) => {
  const message = req.query.msg;
  if (!message) {
    return res.status(400).send("Message is missing");
  }

  const target = req.query.target;
  if (!target) {
    return res.status(400).send("Target is missing");
  }

  // console.log(message, target);

  const socket = sockets[target];
  if (!socket) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Target ${target} is not found`);
  }

  socket.write(message);

  res.send(`send ${message} command to Arduino`);
  // res.send(`${message}, ${target}`);
});

app.get("/change_name", (req, res) => {
  let socket;
  const name = req.query.name + " ";
  if (!name) {
    return res.status(400).send("Name is missing");
  }

  const target = req.query.target;
  if (!target) {
    return res.status(400).send("Target is missing");
  } else {
    const { host, port } = clients[target];
    socket = net.createConnection({ host: host, port: port });
  }

  socket.write("<CHIFNAME>", (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error sending data to Arduino");
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => console.log(""), 1000);
      socket.write(name);

      socket.end();
    }
  });

  // socket.end();
});

app.listen(51983, () => {
  console.log("HTTP server listening on port 51983");
});
```

index.js

```
const path = require("path");
const ipc = ipcMain;
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

let serverProcess;

app.disableHardwareAcceleration();

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500, // Default width : 1600 -> 1000
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "assets/icons/electrosmith.png"),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: __dirname + "/preload.js",
    },
  });
  win.setMenu(null); // Delete line

  win.loadFile("public/index.html");

  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.webContents.session.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(
    (details, callback) => {
      callback({ requestHeaders: { Origin: "*", ...details.requestHeaders } });
    }
  );

  win.webContents.session.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"],
        ...details.responseHeaders,
      },
    });
  });

  ipc.on("send_main_ping", (event, arg) => {
    // console.log("Main received a ping!!!");
  });

  ipc.on("minimizeApp", () => {
    win.minimize();
  });
  ipc.on("maximizeApp", () => {
    if (win.isMaximized()) {
      win.restore();
    } else {
      win.maximize();
    }
  });
  ipc.on("closeApp", () => {
    win.close();
    app.quit();
  });

  ipc.on("message-from-renderer", (event, arg) => {
    // console.log(arg);
  });


};

app.whenReady().then(() => {

  createWindow();
  // serverProcess = spawn("node", ["app.js"], { cwd: "./server/app.js" });
  serverProcess = spawn("node", ["app.js"], { cwd: "." });

  serverProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  serverProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    // console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  serverProcess.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`server process exited with code ${code}`);
  });


  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });

  app.on("will-quit", () => {
    serverProcess.kill();
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    win = null;
    app.quit();
  }

});
```

package.json

```
  "name": "ethernet-json-parser",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"cd frontend && npm run dev\" \"cd server && node app.js\" ",
    "startAll": "concurrently \"cd frontend && npm run dev\" \"cd server && node app.js\" \"electron .\" ",
    "dev": "electron .",
    "test": "electron app.js",
    "build:osx": "electron-builder --mac",
    "build:linux": "npm run build:linux32 && npm run build:linux64",
    "build:linux32": "electron-builder --linux --ia32",
    "build:linux64": "electron-builder --linux --x64",
    "build:win": "npm run build:win32 && npm run build:win64",
    "build:win32": "electron-builder --win --ia32",
    "build:win64": "electron-builder --win --x64"
  },
  "build": {
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "/server/app.js",
        "to": ".",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "productName": "ELECTROSMITH",
    "appId": "kr.co.balhyo.www",
    "asar": false,
    "asarUnpack": [
      "**/*.node"
    ],
    "protocols": {
      "name": "productTest",
      "schemes": [
        "productTest"
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "default"
      ],
      "icon": "/assets/icons/electrosmith"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "title": "tournant",
      "icon": "/assets/icons/electrosmith"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "zip",
        "nsis"
      ],
      "icon": "/assets/icons/electrosmith"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb",
        "rpm",
        "zip",
        "tar.gz"
      ],
      "icon": "/assets/icons/electrosmith"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "installerLanguages": [
        "en_US",
        "ko_KR"
      ],
      "language": "1042"
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources/installer/",
      "output": "build/",
      "app": "."
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "electron-store": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "recoil-persist": "^4.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^23.1.3",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "electron-packager": "^17.1.1"
  }
}
```

I want to run a server of '/server/app.js' when I build an electron, but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried the same executable and productName of package.json, but nothing changed, and I tried to modify the content of extraFilesfilter from "**/*" to "**/*.node", but this also didn't work.